# UIDocument open operation fails

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, icloud

I am using UIDocument to manage iCloud Drive storage for my app. I am using NSMetadataQuery to detect changes in iCloud container. When there's an update from NSMetadataQuery I run a function and try to access the data using UIDocument.

The thing is when I am connected to internet and an update event comes everything works fine and UIDocument opens the document successfully but when I am disconnected from internet and do some changes in my iCloud container and turn the internet back on, the update event comes but UIDocument open fails with following message in the debugger:

> " NoteStack[391:7193] [claims] 7F874C6C-2CF8-46C9-9E50-6881D63A0DE6 grantAccessClaim reply is an error: Error Domain=NSFileProviderErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Your device couldn’t connect to the server. There may be a problem with the server or network." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~fusionengineeringtech~NoteStack/Documents/A69B9860-9668-40FE-9D09-E6ED3ED5B28D/E3C485D5-4D95-4614-971F-70157053D63C/E3C485D5-4D95-4614-971F-70157053D63C.note, NSLocalizedDescription=Your device couldn’t connect to the server. There may be a problem with the server or network., NSUnderlyingError=0x2815c4360 {Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4355 "Couldn’t access your iCloud account. The iCloud servers might be unreachable or your settings might be incorrect." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Couldn’t access your iCloud account. The iCloud servers might be unreachable or your settings might be incorrect.}}} "

I have attach my code for the reference:

```
class Note: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String = ""
    var dateCreated = Date()
    var text: String = ""
}

class NoteDocument: UIDocument {
    var note = Note()
    
    override func load(fromContents contents: Any, ofType typeName: String?) throws {
        if let contents = contents as? Data {
            if let arr = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Note.self, from: contents) {
                self.note = arr
                return
            }
        }
        //if we get here, there was some kind of problem
        throw NSError(domain: "NoDataDomain", code: -1, userInfo: nil)
    }
    
    override func contents(forType typeName: String) throws -> Any {
        if let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self.note) {
            return data
        }
        //if we get here, there was some kind of problem
        throw NSError(domain: "NoDataDomain", code: -2, userInfo: nil)
    }
}

class Model {
    var documents = [NoteDocument]()
    var controller: UICollectionViewController?
    let noteFileExtension = ".note"
    var metadataQuery = NSMetadataQuery()
    
    init() {
        metadataQuery.notificationBatchingInterval = 1
        metadataQuery.searchScopes = [NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDataScope, NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope]
        metadataQuery.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K LIKE %@", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey, "*")
        metadataQuery.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: NSMetadataItemFSNameKey, ascending: true)]
        metadataQuery.start()
        
        let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
        
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(didFinish),
                                                   name: NSNotification.Name.NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGathering,
                                                   object: nil)
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(didStart),
                                                   name: NSNotification.Name.NSMetadataQueryDidStartGathering,
                                                   object: nil)
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(didUpdate),
                                                   name: NSNotification.Name.NSMetadataQueryDidUpdate,
                                                   object: nil)
    }
    
    @objc func didStart(notification: NSNotification) {
        let query: NSMetadataQuery = notification.object as! NSMetadataQuery
        print("didStart found \(query.results.count) items")
    }
    
    @objc func didFinish(notification: NSNotification) {
        let query: NSMetadataQuery = notification.object as! NSMetadataQuery
        print("didFinish found \(query.results.count) items")
    }
    
    @objc func didUpdate(notification: NSNotification) {
        metadataQuery.disableUpdates()

        if let modifications = notification.userInfo {
            if let added = modifications[NSMetadataQueryUpdateAddedItemsKey] as? [NSMetadataItem]
            {
                for item in added {
                    onAdd(item: item)
                }
            }
        }
        
        metadataQuery.enableUpdates()

        print("didUpdate")
    }
    
    func onAdd(item: NSMetadataItem) {
        if let url = item.value(forAttribute: NSMetadataItemURLKey) as? URL {
            if url.pathExtension == "note" {
                let document = NoteDocument(fileURL: url)
                
                document.open { success in
                    if success {
                        let note = document.note
                        if !self.documents.contains(where: {$0.note.id == note.id}) {
                            self.documents.append(document)
                            if let controller = self.controller,
                               let collectionView = controller.collectionView {
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    collectionView.reloadData() //Update UI
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        print("There was an error adding items")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```